# VirtualQueryEx returning zero with no GetLastError()

Tags: c#, winapi, getlasterror

For one of my project, i needed to list all the pages of a process.

So here is the code i made :

```
private List<MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION> GetMemoryInfo()
{
var output = new List<MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION>();
var addy = new IntPtr();

while (true)
{
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION memInfo = new MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION();

    int memDump = VirtualQueryEx(handle, addy, out  memInfo, Marshal.SizeOf(memInfo));


    if (memDump == 0)
    {
        var err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        throw new Exception("GetMemoryInfo failed : GetLastError() : " + new Win32Exception(err).Message);
    }

    if ((memInfo.State & 0x1000) != 0 && (memInfo.Protect & 0x100) == 0)
        output.Add(memInfo);

    addy = new IntPtr(memInfo.BaseAddress.ToInt32() + memInfo.RegionSize);
}

return output;
}
```

Problem is on the execution, VirtualQueryEx returns 0. When i call GetLastError, it also returns zero.
Where is the problem in my code ?

Edit : Here is the declarationof MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION and VirtualQueryEx() :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    protected struct MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr BaseAddress;
        public IntPtr AllocationBase;
        public uint AllocationProtect;
        public uint RegionSize;
        public uint State;
        public uint Protect;
        public uint Type;
    }
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    protected static extern int VirtualQueryEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, out MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer, int dwLength);
```

Comment: Your pinvoke declaration is probably wrong.  We can't see it.

Comment: I just edited the first post. Sorry, i didn't think about it.

Comment: Right, it is wrong.  You forgot to set the SetLastError property to true.

Comment: Indeed, i forgot to set SetLastError. I now have an error 24. Thank you.

Comment: Bad length.  The RegionSize field is an IntPtr.